# Is 'much' adverb in 'half as much again as what Wall Street was predicting'?

Tags: parts-of-speech

From [The Economist:](https://www.economist.com/business/2023/05/29/nvidia-is-not-the-only-firm-cashing-in-on-the-ai-gold-rush)

> On May 24th Nvidia, which designs the semiconductors of choice for
> many ai servers, beat analysts’ revenue and profit forecasts for the
> three months to April and said it expected sales of $11bn in its
> current quarter, half as much again as **what** Wall Street was
> predicting.

Can I replace '$22bn' to 'what'? Namely,

> On May 24th Nvidia, which designs the semiconductors of choice for
> many ai servers, beat analysts’ revenue and profit forecasts for the
> three months to April and said it expected sales of $11bn in its
> current quarter, half as much again as  Wall Street was
> predicting **$22bn**.

Is this replace right?  If so ,does 'much' functions as an adverb ?

Comment: Your sentence is too long. It should be two. That said, you can do this:  half as much again as Wall Street was predicting: $22bn.

Comment: Your title is about "much", but your question is about "what" and "$22bn". What do you really want to learn?

Comment: @gotube Actually, I wanted to ask two questions. The first is whether my substitution is correct, and if so, whether the word "much" is an adverb. Obviously my substitution was not correct, so no one answered my second question...

Comment: @Mr.Wang Also, on this site, we cannot ask two questions in one. If you need the answer to the first before you can ask the second, then ask the first one first.

Comment: @gotube Ok, I'll keep that rule in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance was **better** than forecast; hence, the Wall Street prediction figure has to be lower.  *beat analysts’ revenue and profit forecasts* is a clue in the passage.

*half as much/many again as* is an idiom:

> used to say that the size or amount of one thing is 50 percent more than another

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/half%20as%20much%2Fmany%20again%20as)

Working out the mathematics, we get what Wall Street was predicting to be about $7.3bn.  If you must indicate this figure in the passage, we could say

> ... it expected sales of $11bn in its current quarter, half as much again as the $7.3bn that Wall Street was predicting.

Comment: Or "half as much again as the $7.3bn that Wall Street was predicting"

Comment: Yes, @KateBunting's formulation works, I'm afraid yours ("as what Wall Street was predicting, of about $7.3bn.") does not. If you add it to the end, it would have to be something like "[...] as what Wall Street was predicting, which was about $7.3bn." but that's awkward.

Answer (score 1):

'Much' can be a *determiner*, a *pronoun*, and an *adverb*.

It is usually obvious when it is acting as a determiner, because it will be referring to something *quantifiable* - that is measurable or countable (eg "*it didn't cost much money*"). Likewise, when it is acting as a pronoun it should be clear that it is standing in for an unmentioned quantity (eg "*it doesn't cost much*"). When it is an adverb it is just an intensifier; ie not something you could count like money (eg "*it didn't hurt much*").

What you're looking at here, though is a phrase "*as much... as*". It is used to compare one amount with another. You are correct that £11bn is "half as much as" £22bn. So you could replace this entire phrase with the amounts:

> $11bn is half as much as $22bn

That's just maths, though. It doesn't tell you much. If you removed the phrase and the comparison, you could say:

> it expected sales of $11bn in its current quarter. Wall Street was predicting $22bn.

But this doesn't really give any analysis or comment. It is just two numbers for the reader to make of what they will. Commenting that the actual figure is half as much as predicted is more impactful.

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with your changes. I think that, because you didn't recognise "as much as" as a phrase, you've mistakenly thought that the second 'as' is is just introducing information as to who made the prediction. But it is more than that - it is more like an equation, ie *$11bn = half what Wall Street predicted*.

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested replacement is not correct; it is backwards.

"half as much again" is an idiom, and it means the original quantity, plus half of the original quantity (*again*).

The original quantity was
(x + 1/2x) = 11 billion
or 11 billion / 1.5 = 7.33 billion.

So, the prediction was 7.33 billion, and the actual earnings, half again as much, were 11 billion.

As to "much", let's take a simpler expression that isn't an idiom.
*This amount is as much as that amount.*
The word "much" there is an adjective. The two words "as... as..." are conjunctions used to make comparison.

[Cambridge as... as...](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-as)
"We use as + adjective/adverb + as to make comparisons when the things we are comparing are equal in some way:
*The world’s biggest bull is **as** big **as** a small elephant.* "

The word "half" is an adverb modifying the comparison, as in these examples:
Half as much as
fully as much as
one-tenth as much as
not as much as
twice as much as

*Half again* means, as shown above, the original amount (the prediction) plus half of that prediction.